# How can I retrieve all users from firebase to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have created a Recycler view in my `fragment_add_friends.xml` like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/all_user_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

and I created `all_user_display_layout.xml` file for display each user like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/all_user_image">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/all_user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="full name"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/all_user_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="user status"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `AddFriendsFragment.java` I got the recycler view like below in my on create view method

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_friends, container, false);

        all_user_list = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.all_user_list);
        all_user_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        all_user_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return v;
    }
```

> and I have created a helper class that have Strings name, status,
>   image and there getters setters and constructor and empty construcor because I have to retrieve those data and xml file those things in is `all_user_display_layout.xml`

and I got the database reference like below

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
```

and I create the onViewCreated method like below

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }
```

> after that what are the things that I have to do to get data from
>   fireabse to recycler view

please help me im new to these stuff

[image: database structure]

Comment: Please share your database structure and the exact records that you want to display.

Comment: I include the layout file that have name, image and status, and I have include my database structure Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `users` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root, to get the `name`, `image` and `status`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String image = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            String status = ds.child("status").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(name + " / " + image + " / " + status);
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + image + " / " + status);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
Hemal / https... / Busy
Jake Stewart / https... / Busy
```

Comment: yeah its work like that thanks sir How can i set those values to the the xml file if you can please help me with that it would be really appreciated

Comment: @HemalHerath its very simple stores that value in  **`Arraylist`** of POJO class

Comment: Please see my updated answer. As you probably see, i have added a List in which those values are added for every iteration.

Comment: yeah but I mean the how to set those values to display in layout

Comment: @HemalHerath you use **Recyclerview** to display those value store values in **Arraylist** than pass this arraylist to Recyclerview Adapter i think you have idea of Recyvclerview

Comment: As Prem mentioned, you just need to pass the list to your `Recyclerview Adapter` in order to have the data displyed. Thanks @Prem !

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines from onCreateView

```
 all_user_list = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.all_user_list);
 all_user_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
 all_user_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Add the following code in onViewCreated

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter<<Your-Helper-Class>, ViewHolder> adapter;
     ref = new Firebase("https://<yourapp>.firebaseio.com");

     RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_user_list);
     recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
     recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

     adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter<<Your-Helper-Class>, ViewHolder>(<Your-Helper-Class>.class, android.R.layout.all_user_display_layout.xml, ViewHolder.class, mRef) {
         public void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, <Your-Helper-Class> helper) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(helper.getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);
             viewHolder.name.setText(helper.getName());
             viewHolder.status.setText(helper.getStatus());
         }
     };
     recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }



    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView image;
         TextView name;
         TextView status;

         public ChatMessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             image = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.all_user_image);
             name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.all_user_name);
             status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.all_user_status);
         }
     }
```

Also use Picasso for loading image in imageview. Add these lines in your build.gradle.

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: I cant use something like this recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: and I dont have populateViewholder override method just have onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder

Comment: Add this in build.gradle  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'